# How to order and modify content of List<Cell> using LINQ

Tags: c#, list, sorting

So I have a simple class Cell consisting of coordinates (X, Y)

```
class Cell
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public Cell(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    /* Some methods */
}
```

In main I'm creating a list of Cells `List<Cell> cells` and then filling it with Cells with some random but *not repeating* coordinates. Constraits are: `X >= 1 && X <= 4`, same with Y.

And then I'm sorting this list in such a way, that it will be ordered like indices of a 2D jagged array. Here's what I came up with:

`cells = cells.OrderBy(c => c.X).ThenBy(c => c.Y).ToList();`

After this sort, `cells` will be ordered like this, for example:

`[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 4], [2, 2], [2, 4], [4, 1], [4, 2]`

So it's (kinda) like a jagged array's indices going in order.
The last thing I want to do is to make all Y's go consequentially
 for each X. I'll show you what I mean by using previous sequence:

`[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2], [4, 1], [4, 2]`

^ That, I wanna know how to do it. No Cells added, just changed Y's for corresponding X's.

So how do I do this? Should I use LINQ or just a couple of cycles would do? I'm sure there is a really simple solution to this that I'm missing...

Comment: If the ordered data was `[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 4], [1, 5], [1, 7], [4, 1], [4, 2]` what would you expect the results to be?

Comment: @mjwills `[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 1], [1, 2], [4, 1], [4, 2]` < this must be a final order, that I don't know how to do yet

Comment: How do you get `[0, 1]` if `X >= 1`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke oops, didn't mean to misslead you, my bad.
Of course it goes from 1 to 4

Comment: You could use a `.Select()` to create a new collection (and use an indexer to set the `Y` value)

Comment: Why do you fill the cells with random values, if your final goal are sequent numbers?

Comment: linq is cool, but from a performance point of view, just using `int x = 0, int i = 0; foreach(var cell in cells) { if (cell.X != x) {i = 1; x = cell.X; } cell.Y = i++; }` would be better.

Comment: @mjwills, Its set to 1 if the condition is not met, so it does not really matter what it's initialized as

Comment: OP has already confirmed that `X >= 1` - see my earlier comment and the resulting edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var results = cells.GroupBy(z => z.X)
    .Select(z => z.Select((y, i) => new Cell(z.Key, i + 1)))
    .SelectMany(z => z).ToList();
```

will most likely do what you want. **Also, it is unnecessary to use `OrderBy` / `ThenBy` beforehand.**

`GroupBy` will ensure that all data with the same value of `X` are grouped together. Then we use `Select(y, i)` (where `i` is a zero-based index) to generate the `Y` values from `1..n`, when there are `n` entries with a given value of `X`. This generates an enumerable of enumerables (think of it as an array of arrays) - `SelectMany` flattens that out into a single enumerable. Then `ToList` to generate a `List<Cell>`.

*If you want to avoid `new`ing up new `Cell` objects, then just alter the existing `Cell` objects instead:*

```
var results = cells.GroupBy(z => z.X)
    .Select(z => z.Select((y, i) =>
    {
        y.Y = i + 1; // Change the existing object
        return y;
    })).SelectMany(z => z).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, the second option is exatly what I need!